# WebGL - no matching overloaded function found

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have this WebGL fragment shader on my html file which is running fine, except when I call the first 5 vec2 functions.

```
vec2 subCalc(vec2 z1, vec2 z2){
    return vec2((z1.x - z2.x), (z1.y - z2.x));
}
```

I get this error:

[image: ERROR ALERT ON BROWSER]

It's weird because I use the vec4's, for example 'HSVtoRGB', the code runs fine.

full shaders

```html
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 actualPos;
uniform vec2 drag;
uniform float func;
uniform float n;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float scale;
uniform float test;

vec2 subCalc(vec2 z1, vec2 z2){
    return vec2((z1.x - z2.x), (z1.y - z2.x));
}

vec2 expCalc(vec2 z){
    return vec2(exp(z.x)*cos(z.y),exp(z.x)*sin(z.y));
}

vec2 divCalc(vec2 z1, vec2 z2){
    return vec2((z1.x*z2.x + z1.y*z2.y)/(z2.x*z2.x+z2.y*z2.y),(z1.y*z2.x-z1.x*z2.y)/(z2.x*z2.x+z2*z2.y));
}

vec2 multCalc(vec2 z1, vec2 z2){
    return vec2((z1.x*z2.x - z1.y*z2.y), (z1.y*z2.x + z1.x*z2.y));
}

vec2 sumCalc(vec2 z1, vec2 z2){
    return vec2((z1.x + z2.x), (z1.y + z2.x));
}

vec4 HSVtoRGB(float h, float s, float v)
{
//Convert between the HSV and RGB color model.
//Taken from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html and rewritten for GLSL 
int i;
float f, p, q, t;
vec4 RGB;

if (s == 0.0)
{
// achromatic (grey)
RGB.x = RGB.y = RGB.z = v;
RGB.w = 1.0;
return RGB;
}

h /= 60.0; // sector 0 to 5
i = int(floor(h));
f = h - float(i); // fracional part of h
p = v * (1.0 - s);
q = v * (1.0 - s * f);
t = v * (1.0 - s * (1.0 - f));

if(i==0)
{
RGB.x = v;
RGB.y = t;
RGB.z = p;
}
else if(i==1)
{
RGB.x = q;
RGB.y = v;
RGB.z = p;
}
else if(i==2)
{
RGB.x = p;
RGB.y = v;
RGB.z = t;
}
else if(i==3)
{
RGB.x = p;
RGB.y = q;
RGB.z = v;
}
else if(i==4)
{
RGB.x = t;
RGB.y = p;
RGB.z = v;
}
else if(i==5)
{
RGB.x = v;
RGB.y = p;
RGB.z = q;
}
else
{
RGB.x = 1.0;
RGB.y = 1.0;
RGB.z = 1.0;
}
RGB.w = 1.0;
return RGB;
}



vec4 secondCase(vec4 posi){

    float multX = ((posi.x * posi.x) - (posi.y * posi.y));
    float multY = ((posi.y * posi.x) + (posi.x * posi.y));

    float newX = multX;
    float newY = multY;

    
    
    float r = pow(sqrt((newX)*(newX)+(newY)*(newY)),n);
    for(float i = 0.0; i <=10000.0; i++){
        if(i>=n){break;}
        newX = ((newX * posi.x) - (newY * posi.y));
        newY = ((newY * posi.x) + (newX * posi.y));
    }
    float h = (atan(newY/newX));
    float s = 1.0;
    float v = fract((log2(r)));

    

    h = (h*180.0)/(3.14);

    if(h<0.0)
        h = h*(-1.0);

    if(newX <= 0.0 && newY > 0.0)
        h = 180.0 - h;

    if(newX < 0.0 && newY < 0.0)
        h = 180.0 + h;

    if(newX >= 0.0 && newY < 0.0)
        h = 360.0 - h;

    return HSVtoRGB(h,s,v);

}

vec4 thirdCase(vec4 posi){

    vec2 divi = vec2((100.0*posi.x + 0.0*posi.y)/(posi.x*posi.x+posi.y*posi.y),(0.0*posi.x-100.0*posi.y)/(posi.x*posi.x+posi.y*posi.y));

    vec2 exp = vec2(exp(divi.x)*cos(divi.y),exp(divi.x)*sin(divi.y));
    
    float r = pow(sqrt((exp.x)*(exp.x)+(exp.y)*(exp.y)),n);
    float h = (atan((exp.y/exp.x)));
    float s = 1.0;
    float v = fract((log2(r)));

    h = (h*180.0)/(3.14);

    if(h<0.0)
        h = h*(-1.0);

    if(exp.x <= 0.0 && exp.y > 0.0)
        h = 180.0 - h;

    if(exp.x < 0.0 && exp.y < 0.0)
        h = 180.0 + h;

    if(exp.x >= 0.0 && exp.y < 0.0)
        h = 360.0 - h;

    return HSVtoRGB(h,s,v);

}

vec4 forthCase(vec4 posi){
    
    

    vec2 divi = vec2((100.0*posi.x + 0.0*posi.y)/(posi.x*posi.x+posi.y*posi.y),(0.0*posi.x-100.0*posi.y)/(posi.x*posi.x+posi.y*posi.y));

    vec2 exp = vec2(exp(divi.x)*cos(divi.y),exp(divi.x)*sin(divi.y));
    
    float r = pow(sqrt((exp.x)*(exp.x)+(exp.y)*(exp.y)),n);
    float h = (atan((exp.y/exp.x))*3.0);
    float s = 1.0;
    float v = fract((log2(r)));

    h = (h*180.0)/(3.14);

    if(h<0.0)
        h = h*(-1.0);

    if(exp.x <= 0.0 && exp.y > 0.0)
        h = 180.0 - h;

    if(exp.x < 0.0 && exp.y < 0.0)
        h = 180.0 + h;

    if(exp.x >= 0.0 && exp.y < 0.0)
        h = 360.0 - h;

    return HSVtoRGB(h,s,v);

}



void main() {

    vec4 finalPosition = actualPos;
    finalPosition.x += drag.x;
    finalPosition.y += drag.y;

    finalPosition.x *= test;
    finalPosition.y *= test;
    
    float r = sqrt((finalPosition.x)*(finalPosition.x)+(finalPosition.y)*(finalPosition.y));
    float h = atan((finalPosition.y/finalPosition.x));
    float s = 1.0;
    float v = fract((log2(r)));

    h = (h*180.0)/(3.14);

    if(h<0.0)
        h = h*(-1.0);

    if(finalPosition.x < 0.0 && finalPosition.y > 0.0)
        h = 180.0 - h;

    if(finalPosition.x < 0.0 && finalPosition.y < 0.0)
        h = 180.0 + h;

    if(finalPosition.x > 0.0 && finalPosition.y < 0.0)
        h = 360.0 - h;

    vec2 firstMemb = expCalc(finalPosition);
  

    if(func == 1.0){
        gl_FragColor = HSVtoRGB(h,s,v);
    } else if(func == 2.0){
        gl_FragColor = secondCase(finalPosition);
    } else if(func == 3.0){
        gl_FragColor = thirdCase(finalPosition);
    }

    
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```c
vec2 firstMemb = expCalc(finalPosition);
```

Is trying to pass a `vec4` to a function that takes a `vec2`

Comment: shouldn't `vec2 firstMemb = expCalc(vec2(finalPosition));` work?